# I have a json array object, I have to compare child most node and return complete array object having that particular child alone

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
const jsonArray = {
     "squadName": "Super hero squad",
     "homeTown": "Metro City",
     "formed": 2016,
     "secretBase": "Super tower",
     "active": true,
     "members": [
      {
      "name": "Molecule Man",
      "age": 29,
      "secretIdentity": "Dan Jukes",
      "powers": [
        "Radiation resistance",
        "Turning tiny",
        "Radiation blast"
     ]
   },
   {
    "name": "Madame Uppercut",
    "age": 39,
    "secretIdentity": "Jane Wilson",
    "powers": [
      "Million tonne punch",
      "Damage resistance",
      "Superhuman reflexes"
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "Eternal Flame",
     "age": 1000000,
     "secretIdentity": "Unknown",
     "powers": [
       "Immortality",
       "Heat Immunity",
       "Inferno",
       "Teleportation",
       "Interdimensional travel"
      ]
     }
    ]
   }
```

The above mentioned json array object is all I have

Should compare all child nodes with *"name": "Eternal Flame"*, and I should get output with the child node satisfying that condition.

```
    `{
     "squadName": "Super hero squad",
     "homeTown": "Metro City",
     "formed": 2016,
     "secretBase": "Super tower",
     "active": true,
     "members": [
     {
      "name": "Eternal Flame",
      "age": 1000000,
      "secretIdentity": "Unknown",
      "powers": [
       "Immortality",
       "Heat Immunity",
       "Inferno",
       "Teleportation",
       "Interdimensional travel"
      ]
     }
    ]
   }`
```

Trying to return the data but not have an idea where i'm going wrong, please help me thank sin advance?

```
   `jsonArray.map(member => member.members.forEach(details => {
     const newArray = [];
     if (details.name === 'Eternal Flame') {
       return ***memberDetails***;
     } else return null;}))`
```

Comment: [There's no such thing as a _"JSON array object"_](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). There's no [JSON](http://json.org). `const jsonArray = {}, {}, ...` is invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your JSON structure is invalid (at least the one you've posted).

**I'm going to assume the `jsonArray` is the object data of a squad, with members AND you're searching for a member (node) with the matching name *Eternal Flame***.

Secondly, your code will return the array with the same length as the members array with `null` everywhere except the matching node. To return **only** the matching node (I.e. member)...

```
jsonArray.members.filter(member => member.name === "Eternal Flame") [0]; // [0] Gets the first item of the matching array (Which should have a count of 1 anyway)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the name of each member is unique, you can use:

```js
const newJson = {
  ...jsonArray,
  members: [jsonArray.members.find(m =>  m.name === "Eternal Flame")]
}
```

This approach, first introduces the data of `jsonArray` in `newJson` and then sets the property `members` of `newJson` to an array which only contains the member you are looking for.

If name is not unique you can use:

```js
const newJson = {
  ...jsonArray,
  members: jsonArray.members.filter(m =>  m.name === "Eternal Flame")
}
```

With your data, in both cases the output is:

```
{
   "squadName": "Super hero squad",
   "homeTown": "Metro City",
   "formed": 2016,
   "secretBase": "Super tower",
   "active": true,
   "members": [
      {
         "name": "Eternal Flame",
         "age": 1000000,
         "secretIdentity": "Unknown",
         "powers": [
            "Immortality",
            "Heat Immunity",
            "Inferno",
            "Teleportation",
            "Interdimensional travel"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```